# Escape % in JSON Struct with Angularjs for sending http.GET to the server

Tags: angularjs, json, coldfusion, special-characters, url-encoding

I have a problem when I tried to execute my query with **AngularJS** because there is special character like `%`. I'm using **Coldfusion** as the server.

The URL of the query is:

> http://myApp/index.cfm?method=updateRequest&dateRequest=11/12/2017&requestid=29000&jsStruct={%22ID%22:29000,%22PERSONID%22:13541,%22REQUESTDATE%22:%2211/12/2017%22,%22DESCRIPTION%22:%22test%22,%22MAILCONTENT%22:%22essai%2025%20???%%22,%22OPERATOR%22:%22Sebastien%20AMADEI%22,%22REQUESTTHEME%22:{%22ID%22:2,%22OBSOLETE%22:0,%22NAME%22:%22Economy%20and%20finance%22}}

**My Factory:**

```
app.factory('RequestService', function($http){
    var factory={};

    factory.updateRequest=function(objRequest,id, dateFormat){
        return $http.post('http://myApp/requests.cfc?method=updateRequest&dateRequest=' + dateFormat + '&requestid=' + id + '&jsStruct=' + JSON.stringify(objRequest))
    };

    return factory;
})
```

**My controller in the file app.js**:

```
app.controller('ctrlEditRequests', function ($scope, $routeParams, MyTextSearch, RequestService){

    RequestService.loadRequestsById($routeParams.requestId).success(function(request){

    $scope.submitForm = function(request){
        if($scope.RequestForm.$valid){

            RequestService.updateRequest(request, $routeParams.personId, dateFormat).success(function(){
                window.location="#/view-contacts/" + $scope.request.PERSONID;
            }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {

            });

        }
    };      
});
```

Here the structure is:

```
"{"ID":29000,"PERSONID":13541,"REQUESTDATE":"11/12/2017","DESCRIPTION":"test","MAILCONTENT":"essai 25 ??? 1%1","OPERATOR":"Sebastien AMADEI","REQUESTTHEME":{"ID":2,"OBSOLETE":0,"NAME":"Economy and finance"}}"
```

I cannot execute the query because there is the character `%` in the field Mail Content. I have done a `stringify` but it's not sufficient.

I don't know how to escape special characters before sending to the server in order to execute the query.

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, the `"%"` character is being properly encoded. It is the `"?"` character that is improperly encoded.

In the URL, AngularJS does not [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the following characters:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

To properly percent encode search parameters in a URL, use the `params` property of the `$http` config object:

```
app.factory('RequestService', function($http){
    var factory={};

    factory.updateRequest=function(objRequest,id, dateFormat){
        var params = {
            method: "updateRequest",
            dateRequest: dateFormat,
            requestid: id,
            jsStruct: objRequest
        };
        var config = { params: params };
        return $http.get("http://myApp/requests.cfc", config)
    };

    return factory;
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)
- [MDN JavaScript Web API Reference - encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)
- [MDN JavaScript Web API Reference - encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)